# Running diskpart in the same window from where it is called

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line-tool, diskpart

Calling diskpart.exe opens it in a new legacy terminal windows. I want to run diskpart.exe within the same terminal window where it was called from. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try launching the terminal with administrator privileges.

Comment: This works. But is there any way to elevate the running terminal window to admin privilege with a command?